# generated: undefined reference to `BMWIntegrationTest_RunAutomatedTestSuite'

Tags: c, undefined

Hi  I recently learned c and cpp. I see undefine reference with my below code

foo.h

```
#ifndef __BMWReceiverIntegrationTests_h__
#define __BMWReceiverIntegrationTests_h__

#if ( BUILD_TEST )

#include <stdio.h>
#include "CommonServices.h"
#include "BMWReceiver.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif


Status BMWIntegrationTest_RunTestSuite( void );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // BUILD_TEST
#endif /* __BMWReceiverIntegrationTests_h__ */
```

foo.c

```
Status BMWIntegrationTest_RunTestSuite( void )
{
    Status  err         = kNoErr;
    
err = start_engine();
    
exit:
    return ( err );
}
```

Called from below main.c

main.c

```
#include "foo.h"

BMWIntegrationTest_RunTestSuite() // linker error
```

With above code I see linker error as below

```
 generated: undefined reference to `BMWIntegrationTest_RunTestSuite'
```

Note: When  comment out caller BMWIntegrationTest_RunTestSuite from the main.cpp. Then the build is success.

Comment: Show your link command.  Also, is that really what `main.c` contains?  What you posted is not valid C.

Comment: Identifiers that start with underscore are reserved.  The defacto standard for header file guard is upper case file name with period replaced with underscore.  In your case FOO_H